# How to hover over one element and apply animation effects to a different one

Tags: html, css

There are a couple questions like this, but to make it clear, I need to hover over one element and have another element transition, not simply having it pop back and forth (for example, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/btevfik/YC2tg/)).

Essentially, this is what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/jMEL7/2/
Except that it needs to transition when I'm hovering over either of the two buttons and not when I'm hovering over the image.

Iv'e tried using selectors, but that doesn't work. I wish I could just do this:

```
    #lb:hover {
    h {
        webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
        transform:rotate(270deg)
    }
}
```

From the other posts, it seems JS is the only way. I don't know jQuery, so I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use adjacent sibling combinator (`+`), but only if `#h` is after `#lb` in the HTML.

```
#lb:hover + #b {
    // your style
}
```

If there are other elements between `#h` and `#lb`, you can use (`~`) combinator.

```
#lb:hover ~ #h {
    // your style
}
```

**e.g -**

```
#lb:hover ~ #h {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg)
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/jMEL7/3/)

For child and siblings selector [read](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)

Finally

```
#main > a:nth-child(1):hover ~ a:nth-child(3) img {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg)
}
#main > a:nth-child(2):hover ~ a:nth-child(3) img {
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    transform:rotate(270deg)
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/jMEL7/8/)

Comment: You obviously changed the OP's HTML code, that may not be what the OP wants. We can't have a pure CSS solution without changing the OP's HTML code.

Comment: Yeh I know, but OP gave a link of what he essentially wanted, I made edit in that.

Comment: I should have planned in advance, but putting <form>/<a> tags around the image and buttons breaks the combinator(to link them). Any way to fix that?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle to play with?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jMEL7/5/ Something like this, I guess. The only difference from the one you provided is an extra button and <a> tags surrounding the them and the image.

Answer (score 1):

I placed your input tag before img tag so I can use adjacent sibling combinator(+)

```
<input type="button" id="lb" value="Button">
<img src="http://playrust.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/rust-icon-512.png" id="h" height="130px"/>
```

CSS code:

```
#lb:hover + #h {
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);transform:rotate(270deg);
}
```

[**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/shoaibista/jMEL7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

---

```
<input type="button" id="lb" value="Button">
<img src="http://playrust.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/rust-icon-512.png" 
     id="h" height="130px"/>
```

**CSS**

---

```
#lb {
    float:right;
    color:#6C2D58;
    font-size:40px;
    font-family:Impact;
    transition: 1s;
}
#lb:hover {
    background-color:#D88E79;
}
#h {
    transition:1s;
}
#lb:hover ~ #h {
-webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);transform:rotate(270deg);
}
```

## Fiddle Demos

---

- [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yke7/1/)
- [Full Page Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yke7/1/embedded/result/)